# Crashes with backtrace in Ubuntu after few minutes of use

Tags: linux

Blender 2.8 keeps crashing after a bit of use within Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.

I've run Blender from command-line which on start-up returned this (may not be of much use):

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 75)
Build: 2019-07-29 17:17:04 Linux Release
argv[0] = ./blender
argv[1] = -d
Read prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.80/config/userpref.blend
read file 
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
found bundled python: /home/user/Downloads/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.80/python
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

Info: Total files 0 | Changed 0 | Failed 0
Info: Copied 1 selected objects

blo_find_main: added new lib /tmp/copybuffer.blend
read file /tmp/copybuffer.blend
  Version 280 sub 75 date unknown hash 
Info: 1 objects pasted

Skipping auto-save, modal operator running, retrying in ten seconds...
Info: Total files 0 | Changed 0 | Failed 0
Info: Copied 1 selected objects

blo_find_main: found library /tmp/copybuffer.blend
read file /tmp/copybuffer.blend
  Version 280 sub 75 date unknown hash 
Info: 1 objects pasted

Skipping auto-save, modal operator running, retrying in ten seconds...
Info: Total files 0 | Changed 0 | Failed 0
Info: Copied 1 selected objects

blo_find_main: found library /tmp/copybuffer.blend
read file /tmp/copybuffer.blend
  Version 280 sub 75 date unknown hash 
Info: 1 objects pasted

Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

Skipping auto-save, modal operator running, retrying in ten seconds...
Skipping auto-save, modal operator running, retrying in ten seconds...
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch15: krec 0 pushes 1 bufs 18 relocs 0
```

Then after some use Blender crashed. And when it crashed it my command-line output ended with:

```
nouveau:    0x0000ca96
nouveau:    0x1000f010
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the `blender.crash.txt` ended with:

```
# backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x1369c1d]
./blender() [0x1153279]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7fe477c0df20]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so(+0x62c9d8) [0x7fe4504259d8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so(+0x5ca839) [0x7fe4503c3839]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so(+0x6c15c3) [0x7fe4504ba5c3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so(+0x5cb7c0) [0x7fe4503c47c0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so(+0x5cb932) [0x7fe4503c4932]
./blender(gpu_select_pick_load_id+0x65) [0x40fbe75]
./blender() [0x2a1a6a3]
./blender() [0x2a2f8ed]
./blender() [0x2a13851]
./blender(DRW_draw_select_loop+0x41d) [0x2a13c9d]
./blender(view3d_opengl_select+0x590) [0x2d00e60]
./blender() [0x2cf3055]
./blender() [0x2cf4dea]
./blender() [0x2cf59be]
./blender() [0x1519add]
./blender() [0x151c09a]
./blender() [0x151ccae]
./blender() [0x151ed9e]
./blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x4e5) [0x151f305]
./blender(WM_main+0x20) [0x1514c20]
./blender(main+0x2fe) [0x10c0abe]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7fe477bf0b97]
./blender() [0x114fb9c]
```

I've run Blender multiple times and keep getting this same issue. I've run Blender from snap and I've tried downloading it and using the executable.

Additional information: I've got 8Gb of RAM, a I7 4790k, and a GTX 970.

Comment: This looks like a nouveau driver issue. Can you try with the official Nvidia driver and see if that works or update your graphics driver?

Comment: @rjg that's worked - it is no longer crashing , thank you so much :)